# sails.js publishCreate omit socket not working

Tags: model, socket.io, sails.js

I'm having some trouble with publishCreate method of a model, here's my code. My intention is to send the new message (and send a notification) to everybody in chat except the guy who created the message. So far so good, everything works except the **socketToOmit** part, I'm passing the socket in the request to omit but he isn't omitted, he receives the message too.

```
Message.publishCreate({
      id: created_message.id,
      message: created_message.message,
      sender_nickname: created_message.sender_nickname,
      sender_id: created_message.sender_id,
      createdAt: created_message.createdAt.toISOString()
}, req.socket);
```

Comment: By any chance, were you able to find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use an array (containing req.socket as only element) as the second arguments of the publishCreate method ?

```
Message.publishCreate({
  id: created_message.id,
  message: created_message.message,
  sender_nickname: created_message.sender_nickname,
  sender_id: created_message.sender_id,
  createdAt: created_message.createdAt.toISOString()
}, [req.socket]);
```